# Do we really need a "firstworldproblems" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Yeah, I know it was [funny](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/first-world-problems) to tag [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6465/what-can-i-use-instead-of-a-corkscrew) as  [firstworldproblems](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firstworldproblems), but now it looks like people are trying to use it for [legitimate questions scoped to the first world](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/are-hospitality-exchange-services-reasonably-safe-to-use-in-first-world-countrie).

I've retagged that second post as just [first-world](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-world), but I thought I'd ask for some community feedback before nuking the tag completely, lest I be accused of being a humorless prude.

So, should I just remove that tag from the only post it's currently on?  Or do people think it could actually become a useful tag for this site?

Comment: The crowd has spoken. It's gone now.

Comment: Because one user misused it, it should be removed/banned? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @iHaveacomputer: It's not banned. (I'm not a mod, I can't do that even if I wanted.) It was used on two questions, on one of which it was clearly incorrect and on the other of which it was merely there as a joke. I removed it from both, but of course nothing stops you from adding it back if you _really_ think it should be there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I definitely vote for removal. It's funny to those who get it, but it's not useful and potentially misleading.

Comment: @pnuts well this was from 4 years ago...

Answer (score 5):

Does the tag add any significant/useful information, or is it (at best) a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?  Personally, I would remove it.